# How to point a link retrieved form a database to an absolute path in PHP so it work?

Tags: php

I have a database that stores the link. This value "link" is later read by my script and a user can click on a link to go to that link.

The links work with no issue when the user is on any page that is saved/hosted in the root directory /myroot/

But when a user clicks on the link while on a page the is saved/hosted on a different path saved on (ie. /myroot/news/feed.php) the link does not work.. "it seems to me that the script is not ale to tell where it is currently located so it does not know where to take you)

I tried to provide the root path of the site (ie. /myroot/{the link} but that did not work either.

How can I fix the URL so that the script knows where is the true location of the file?

thanks

Comment: is your link relative link (i.e. not start with a slash '/')? if yes, add a slash at the start, so that it always refer to the link destination at the root

Comment: While `echo`ing links from `/myroot/news/feed.php` script , try pre-pending the links with `../` .

Comment: @DavidLin the link always starts with the /  but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a starting point so you can give absolute links instead of relative links.  Look through the `$_SERVER[]` array, there are some elements that tell you where your directory location is on your site.

Comment: Hi I am trying to use the $_SERVER but I am not sure what is the correct option. I have tried using DOCUMENT_ROOT but that did not work. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myroot/' . $dynamic_link and that did not work.

Comment: Should be just `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $dynamic_link`.